# I'm using https://www.chartjs.org/ ... how could i get the graph data by clicking the x-axis label ChartJS ReactJS .?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

[image]

need to select xaxis data .. for example if i select Jul 15 the Jul15 value should get..

example[image]

is there any solution for this requirement, please..?

Comment: Have you tried [getElementsAtEvent](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getelementsatevente)?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi L ---  i've tried .. it only get the values .. but i need to draw a line like the above graph.. is that possible

Comment: Oh I see, so you want a crosshair that moves with your cursor, is that it? And does it move with the cursor or do you want it to appear only on click?

Comment: i want to appear only on click

Comment: when click on labels and data

Comment: do you know any solutions for it... kindly please tell me if you have any ..! @GhassenLouhaichi

Comment: I am looking through the documentation but cannot find anything, the only thing I found is this plugin: [chartjs-plugin-crosshair](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-crosshair), but it seems to work on hover, not on click.